# How to prevent dialog from closing automatically on click in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, dialog

I am developing an application in which i create a Dialog with Edit Field and save/Cancel button, i use validation on edit field,i want that if user enter valid entry and click save then the dialog should close but now the problem is when user click on save without enter any text in edit field dialog closes automatically,i want to prevent it after entering valid entry dialog should close.

I give cancel button to discard dialog.

Please help..how to achieve this..........

Comment: looks like you just need to add some validation in Save button listener.

Comment: Yes...can you please guide me...how to achive thid

Answer (score 2):

```
 mOKButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field f, int arg1) {
                if(_editText.getText()=="")
                              {
                             // do nothing 
                               }
                                 else{ 
                _editText.setText(items[getSelectedIndex()]);
                close();
                             } 
            }
        });
```

Comment: this is right but how to add this listener to dialog buttons and if user click on save button without entering any word than dialog should be remain visible...it seema u add lisner other than dialog button.